# Seding images over json and result in distorted image

Tags: php, json

I am sending images using php 5.6 by encoding them base64 and then putting it in an json encoded object together with additional data, to the browser (Firefox 47 as well as chrome 52). There I create a data URI. All Data i receive correctly but the images are distorted having stripes.

[[image: Distortrd Image[1]]

PHP:

The Database contain the raw image binary. The queryTableObj() method creates an array of objects containing the database rows.

```
        $aMl = $oMl->queryTableObj("
        select
            maengel.idMaengel,
            maengel.Pos,
            .
            .
            .
            maengel.Photo1,
            maengel.Photo2,
            maengel.Photo3,
            maengel.Photo4,
            maengel.mime1,
            maengel.mime2,
            maengel.mime3,
            maengel.mime4
        from maengel
        left join beteiligte on maengel.idBeteiligte=beteiligte.idBeteiligte
        where maengel.idProjekt=$idProjekt
        order by Pos
    ");
    if ($oMl->rows > 0) {
        for ($n=0; $n<count($aMl); $n++) {
            for ($i=1; $i<5; $i++) {
                $ph = "Photo$i";
                $aMl[$n]->$ph = base64_encode($aMl[$n]->$ph);
            }
        }
        $s = json_encode($aMl);
        echo ($s);
    } else {
        echo "NONE";
    }
```

javascript reading the data:

```
    readMaengel: function(func) {
    $.post(location.href, {
        cmd: 'MLreadMaengel'
    }, function(cData) {
        if (cData === 'NONE') {
            ml.aMaengel = [];
        } else {
            ml.aMaengel = JSON.parse(cData);
        }
        if (func) {
            func();
        }
    });
},
```

javascript displaying the image:

```
       var pp = $('<div/>')
            .attr('id', 'photoPad')
            .appendTo(iv);
    var ix = $(this).parent().parent().attr('ix');
    for (var tn, img, src, ph, mm, i=0; i<4; i++) {
        tn = $('<div/>')
                .attr('imageno', i)
                .addClass('thumbnail')
                .click(function() {
                    ml.selectPhoto($(this).attr('imageno'), ix);
                })
                .appendTo(pp);
        img = $('<img>').appendTo(tn);
        ph = 'Photo'+(i+1);
        mm = 'mime'+(i+1);
        if (ml.aMaengel[ix][ph] !== null) {
            src = ml.aMaengel[ix][mm]+','+ml.aMaengel[ix][ph];
            img.attr('src', src);
        }

    }
```

Comment: You provided no PHP code, no Javascript code and no JSON data. We can't magically guess what the cause of your problem is. Click "edit" below your question to update it with relevant information.